# Correctly using union types and comparisons

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator, union-types

I'm pretty new to TypeScript, and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around defining a variable to be a union type and using a ternary operator, which is throwing a compile error.

I have a variable that I expect to be one of three specific values, and then to render in my React module based on the value of the variable.

Here I define the type and apply it to the variable, and declare the variable as that type:

```
type voteStatus = "vote" | "show" | "none";
let votable: voteStatus;
votable = "none";
```

Where I have `votable = "none"` is where I'd do some logic to apply one of the three values to the variable. For the moment in development I'm just assigning the value.

So within the returned JSX, I have this:

```
{ votable === "vote" ? (some JSX) : votable === "show" ? (different JSX) : (third JSX) }
```

What I'm getting is this compile error for each of the two comparisons in the ternary (the specific error below is for the first one):

```
This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"none"' and '"vote"' have no overlap.ts(2367)
```

I feel I'm missing some basic function here, but I'm not understanding what it is, and I haven't been finding it when I search. When I assign the value to `votable`, I get the result I expect: if I assign it "vote", "show" or "none" then no error, but if I assign it anything else, I get a compile error. But I get this error when trying to compare.

Comment: Because it'll *always* be whatever value you give it. TS is warning you that some code will never run.

Comment: So the union type restriction is only in play until the value is assigned? This feels like a lack of understanding of a basic principle on my part. Should I just not be typing the variable? That works, but it feels like I'm not honoring correct TypeScript conventions.

Comment: Oh, wait, I get it now. It will always be "vote" because that's how I assigned it: `votable = "vote"`. When I switch the code to randomly assign one of the three, then the compile errors go away.